# Vertical Scroller animation

Tags: android

Is possible to do a vertical scroller animation in Android without using javascript? Anybody knows a tutorial o a web page with a helpful code? thanks

Comment: like this http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/icarousel/example5.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you mean by vertical animation but I think [this tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=343) can help you.

Animations of views are based on `Interpolator`s that [you can set](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setInterpolator%28android.view.animation.Interpolator%29), and one of them is the `LinearInterpolator` which is detailed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LinearInterpolator.html).

**EDIT, further to the comments below**:

This is something you can do with the scrolling and animation features of the `View` class, as [described here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) (ctrl-f "Scrolling" and "Animation" in that page).

Should the API level you are using be too low, this is also something you can do with a `Thread` that modified the position of the `TextView` embedded in your layout or that uses the `scrollXX()` functions. This is also described in the page linked above.

Comment: Thank you but isn´t that I want. I want to do this http://zendold.lojcomm.com.br/icarousel/example5.asp but for Android. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the viewflipper control.

I've tried this in the past and it works well.  You can also use ViewAnimator class

**UPDATE**

The google documentation is a bit hard to chew through.  You may wish to try this [simple tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-use-viewflipper) first.